# jQuery. Cool slide effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Here](http://www.alibaba.com/) you could see Price Watch block (or Trade Updates Worldwide). Prices move with cool slide effect. With what kind of function it is possible to do that effect in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a beautiful implementation of this, check out the plugin: [Totem - an animated vertical ticker](http://buildinternet.com/project/totem/).

If you're looking for code inspiration to replicate the functionality, the [source](https://github.com/buildinternet/totem/blob/master/js/jquery.totemticker.js) is on Github.

Answer (score 2):

It is using :

```
<ul id="sliding">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

and

```
jQuery('sliding').animate({top:'-=20px'});
```

Comment: This draft is what I needed:                `$("#PWLine1>li").css('position', 'relative');
                $("#PWLine1").find("li:eq(0)").animate({"top":'-=15px'}, "slow");
                $("#PWLine1").find("li:eq(1)").animate({"top":'-=15px'}, "slow");`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`.

However I find it annoying.

But hey it's all a matter of taste :D

Comment: I've done this way, but it is not what they did. $("ul").find("li:eq(0)").slideUp(); - it just slides li element at the same possition

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
<ul class="slide">
    <li class="currentSlide"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

```
// every few seconds:
$('#slide').find('.currentSlide').first().removeClass('currentSlide').slideUp().next().slideDown().addClass('currentSlide');
```

Comment: This work, but not in the way on that web site. In your variant, first `li`  does not move to the top. It just slides at the same position.